# How can I store point voxel terrain in octrees

Tags: voxels, octree, storage

I am writing a voxel engine in LWJGL3 - binding for OpenGL 4 for JVM.
Recently I implemented an octree storage of cubic voxels.
In my implementation each leaf node of an octree has one voxel, voxels can't overlap each over.
But now I changed my mind and my goal is to create a dynamic point voxel engine.
How can I store point voxels in an octree ?
My reference is EverQuest Next Landmark.

Answer (score 1):

What you would do is have a limited depth for your octree and allow multiple voxels per leaf. I used a depth of around 6-8 for spatial partitioning for collision detection but for voxels you'll probably need more; it's up to you. You'll also need a limit to stored voxels before splitting, say 10 for the sake of example. As your populate your octree when you hit 10 voxels in a leaf you'll split it and move the voxels into their new leaves. Once a leaf is at your maximum depth you should no longer split it and just let your voxels fill the leaves.

Comment: Ok. But where and how do I store the connection(indices) of point voxels and what if multiple connected point voxels are located at different nodes of a tree ? Or even multiple neighboring chunks of a world? (World is divided into chunks, each chunk is an octree)

Comment: If this is just terrain, why do the voxels need to know about each other? Or maybe I'm just confused when you mean "connected". If you need to know what's nearby a voxel you could get its Octree Node and see it's sibling voxels. You could also get its node and check the nearby nodes. If you needed to check across octrees why not have an octree of octrees?

Comment: If there is no connection between them, then how do I create correct triangles from them ? Each voxel is just a vertex and I need to maintain the correct order, indexing, to form correct shapes

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your use of voxels for some reason. Is it possible to "connect" the voxels before partitioning them with the Octree?

Comment: @ Honeybunch Not sure, in my cubic voxel octree I firstly populate a tree, then build it, then create a mesh for the whole chunk based on the tree. Maybe i should just connect the neighboring voxels. But, again, what if they are in different nodes or chunks. Making one octree for the whole world is not ideal i think, as a world is not a cube, its y axis is limited

Comment: I think that my knowledge of octrees in the application of voxels is too limited to be of much use. I suggest you research Sparse Voxel Octrees (SVOs) as it seems to be related to what you're looking for. 

I believe SVOs are put to use in Gigavoxel: http://maverick.inria.fr/Publications/2011/Cra11/

Comment: @Russoul Who says that a voxel worlds y axis is limited? My voxel game is not.